# php get system informations ram usage and storage usage

Tags: php

Hey guys i am currently working on a little script which shows me cpu load, ram usage and storage usage. I have already managed to get the cpu usage with this little script:

```
$dat = getrusage();
$usertime= $dat['ru_utime.tv_usec'];
$systemtime= $dat['ru_stime.tv_usec'];
$finalresultcpu= ($systemtime/$usertime);
$cpuload = $finalresultcpu * 10;
echo $cpuload;
```

So now i want to get ram usage and storage usage too. The web server is running on a Linux machine. I know there is the monitor script phpsysinfo, but i want to use my own solution. Then i tried `shell_exec`, but this wasn't really helpful. Has someone an idea how i can solve this with php or with a combination of php and javascript?

Comment: The phpsysinfo script is up on github: https://github.com/rk4an/phpsysinfo. Nothing useful in there?

Comment: i looked over it but i doesn't get it how they read out the systemstats

Comment: Have you actually looked at the code?

Comment: Yes it looks like they are using a lot of java script. I don't really understand their code.

Comment: https://github.com/rk4an/phpsysinfo/tree/master/plugins <-- this contains almost all PHP.

Comment: @PeeHaa Ok you are wright but which plugin tells me cpu usage and which ram and which storage. Thats my problem.

Comment: I'm not here to do your research :)

Comment: @Pgr456: Either you need to search or others. As you are looking for an individual solution (*"i want to use my own solution"*) it is your turn to look there *before asking a question*.

Comment: @hakre i looked there before.

Comment: @Pgr456: Yes, obviously, as you wrote in your question, you don't want to do it that way. So now, go on, look more, look into the places you like, find them. That is called *research* you see *re* and *search*. So you search over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know this code will only be running under Linux, you can use the special `/proc/meminfo` file to get information about the system's virtual memory subsystem. The file has a form like this:

```
MemTotal:       255908 kB
MemFree:         69936 kB
Buffers:         15812 kB
Cached:         115124 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:          92700 kB
Inactive:        63792 kB
...
```

That first line, `MemTotal: ...`, contains the amount of physical RAM in the machine, minus the space reserved by the kernel for its own use. It's the best way I know of to get a simple report of the usable memory on a Linux system. You should be able to extract it via something like the following code:

```
<?php
  $fh = fopen('/proc/meminfo');
  $mem = 0;
  while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
    $pieces = array();
    if (preg_match('^MemTotal:\s+(\d+)\skB$', $line, $pieces)) {
      $mem = $pieces[1];
      break;
    }
  }
  fclose($fh);

  echo "$mem kB RAM found"; ?>
```

(Please note: this code may require some tweaking for your environment.)

Comment: I tried your script and it gives me 20 KB RAM found does this mean currently 20kb of ram are in use?